# Twisted and PyBluez working together?

Tags: python, bluetooth, twisted

I want to use twisted and bluetooth together. At the moment I am doing this with PyBluez running in an twisted thread.

PyBluez just creates some socket (or socket-like? it has a file descriptor like a normal socket) object, basically you do:

```
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((device_id,1))
```

Can't I just insert that socket into the twisted reactor somehow and connect it with a Protocol?

Comment: Just curious. Did you ever get this to work? Any issues? I'm trying to implement the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a class implementing IReadDescriptor (or IWriteDescriptor) and connect it to reactor, like in [this example](https://github.com/jdavisp3/twisted-intro/blob/master/twisted-client-1/get-poetry.py).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I also found http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/_posixserialport.py as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I found this project which combines pybluez with twisted:  http://pydoc.net/airi/0.1.1/airi.twisted_bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

This [piece of code](https://github.com/proquar/twisted-stuff/blob/master/bluez/bluezSocket.py) actually helped me a lot. I now have a working implementation in Twisted.

Comment: That is the one I wrote. Worked good enough for my needs. Glad it was of some help to you.